# d3 bar chart with brush

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 bar chart that shows a series of bars using data from a JSON file. By default all the data is shown on the chart and the user can use the brush feature of d3 to zoom in on a particular part of the chart.

I have setup a plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/TJrbCN2tUOlngQbjogCJ?p=preview

However I have a few issues:

1.) The xAxis is a blurred mess of labels instead of showing just an average of months.

The xAxis are setup like:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, mainWidth], 0);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom')
          .innerTickSize(-mainHeight)
          .outerTickSize(0)
          .tickPadding(10);
xScale.domain(data.map(function (d) {
      return d.date;
  }));
```

Is there anything wrong with that?

2.) When dragging the brush it causes the xAxis to only show two labels which do change to the correct start and end dates of the brush, but it doesn't show the dates in between like normal.

3.) The bars don't zoom to what you have brushed to, you still see the default bars in the defaultRange function.

Answer (score 2):

To be completely honest, the reason your question isn't getting answered (even with the bounty) is your code is unreadable and difficult to tackle.  I initially set out to "fix" it but quickly became lost in so many widths, heights and margins I just couldn't follow it.  So, what can we do here?

First, use `d3.js` version 4.  Nothing wrong with version 3 but for new development it's probably better to **not** start with deprecated, unsupported software.

Second, look for a canonical example of what you are trying to do.  Anything by M. Bostock is **the** starting point you should be following.  Cut/paste and start modifying.  In your case, I would have started from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172).

Starting with that base-line, I was able to fit in your data and switch it to a bar chart in about 10 minutes.  Here is [the code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fdh5MglPWCqPUPtqeBqP?p=preview).

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var area = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Total); });

var area2 = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.Date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.Total); });

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/58063c0fe4b0bcac9f814ee6", function(error, data) {
  
  if (error) throw error;
  
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Total; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());
  
  focus.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Total); })
      .attr("width", width / data.length - 2)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Total); });

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());
});

function brushed() {
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  focus.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Date); });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, would it be possible to show an example with stacked bar chart? In addition, my xaxis is not of the type date but string.